# can't find Camera Roll album in Smart Album iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13, photolibrary, camera-roll, phassetcollection

I ran into a problem. There were 15 `albums` for type `smartAlbum` in `AssetCollection` before `iOS 13`, but with `iOS 13`, the number became `14`. `Camera Roll` disappeared from it. 
Here Code of fetching albums:

```
func loadAlbums() {
    var albums:[AlbumModel] = [AlbumModel]()
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    let userAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, options: options)
    userAlbums.enumerateObjects { [weak self] (object: AnyObject!, count: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer) in
        if object is PHAssetCollection {
            let obj: PHAssetCollection = object as! PHAssetCollection
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
            if let arrayAllowedTypes = self?.arrayAllowedSubtypesRawValues, arrayAllowedTypes.contains(obj.assetCollectionSubtype.rawValue) {
                let photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: obj, options: fetchOptions)
                let newAlbum = AlbumModel(name: obj.localizedTitle ?? String.empty, count: photos.count, collection:obj, firstAsset: photos.firstObject)
                albums.append(newAlbum)
            }
        }
    }
    allowedAlbums = albums
    selectedAlbum = albums.first(where: { (album) -> Bool in
        album.collection.assetCollectionSubtype.rawValue == 209 // Camera roll
    })
}
```

and result **iOS 13**:

```
<PHFetchResult: 0x280560960> count=14
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de1b9d0> B93E78CF-FBE8-4791-9B63-009AC9F40FCE/L0/040, title:"Panoramas", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/201
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de21470> FA7600A5-2B42-4C6F-AC50-B604810BC06B/L0/040, title:"Favorites", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/203
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de06aa0> 4329C50B-EE1D-494A-8585-5FC1DBFE890F/L0/040, title:"Slo-mo", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/208
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de0f910> C32B141D-3BCB-4525-8EAD-A24DEE904F60/L0/040, title:"Live Photos", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/213
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de1aa90> 2355B0FA-6CDD-4B59-A089-5CA2CCD059DF/L0/040, title:"Videos", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/202
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de1abd0> F71FE5C0-D5CD-4417-8666-F11C85240448/L0/040, title:"Animated", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/214
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de10040> 1B2B6D54-1622-4953-87BD-7FF112D3F886/L0/040, title:"Selfies", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/210
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de10180> B2D3ECEE-E0D0-44E9-94F6-F9C076B7E91A/L0/040, title:"Time-lapse", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/204
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de102c0> CDBCF8A4-50ED-4709-809A-BFC2C3B8BFE7/L0/040, title:"Hidden", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/205
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de10400> 776A0192-C323-4932-9328-50D9C7A364FE/L0/040, title:"Portrait", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/212
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de10540> 46B7DFE0-F9EA-46DA-8C51-5570E3AF37AB/L0/040, title:"Bursts", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/207
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de10680> 5EF48500-3FAA-415A-800C-C160CC8D1A19/L0/040, title:"Recents", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/209
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de296c0> F28207C8-9B4F-44A8-9F5B-32E6C6169B6E/L0/040, title:"Long Exposure", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/215
<PHAssetCollection: 0x14de29800> 4426D307-05B1-42C5-9F9B-391EA25CDDA2/L0/040, title:"Screenshots", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/211
```

result **iOS 12**

```
<PHFetchResult: 0x280c51a80> count=15
<PHAssetCollection: 0x1057046e0> 70B8F334-A376-4EFF-B92B-E3329F97F7B1/L0/040, title:"Recently Added", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/206
<PHAssetCollection: 0x105749e90> DA0DDAE1-1028-469D-B700-6F52F9F375B1/L0/040, title:"Portrait", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/212
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d320> 70B0A71A-08D2-4C3C-B96E-5380CAA83A36/L0/040, title:"Slo-mo", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/208
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d440> 99DB1706-09FB-4ADD-AAF9-46CC47AEAF49/L0/040, title:"Time-lapse", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/204
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d620> 91D9696D-E4CC-46E8-AABD-E6A90D06D954/L0/040, title:"Animated", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/214
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d740> 19FA3952-F1B0-469E-82C2-A983879322E2/L0/040, title:"Screenshots", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/211
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d860> D9D5099F-FA01-4903-B611-A3484ED53FDE/L0/040, title:"Favorites", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/203
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574d980> 5A27E642-D6DD-4DFE-B90E-6BD17F5C73B6/L0/040, title:"Long Exposure", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/215
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574daa0> 9C5D6211-B455-419A-BB2C-59AED1F76F46/L0/040, title:"Videos", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/202
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574dbc0> 35802A7D-CD77-4B0A-BCE8-F10F784EE03A/L0/040, title:"Selfies", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/210
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574dce0> DD650AAF-3E39-46AE-952F-484857514CD4/L0/040, title:"Live Photos", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/213
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574de00> 5CFEE773-4485-4B7C-A9AF-9DF0FDAB90F4/L0/040, title:"Hidden", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/205
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574df20> 3B453048-7296-4010-9E3A-0F812FC2B1FA/L0/040, title:"Panoramas", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/201
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574e040> 7F229A8E-96DB-4ABD-97FD-70745E4E52D6/L0/040, title:"All Photos", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/209
<PHAssetCollection: 0x10574e160> 5A43BE12-37E6-4617-920E-8600C21D4B03/L0/040, title:"Bursts", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/207
```

My question is: where Camera Roll (All Photos) album located now? how can I get it?

Comment: under the All Photos album listed above?

Comment: could you please clarify, @Scriptable

Comment: I read it wrong, forget my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems Apple removed Camera Roll album in iOS 13: https://appletoolbox.com/heres-everything-new-in-photos-and-camera-in-ios-13/

`The Camera Roll (All Photos) placement has changed in iOS 13. It has been removed from the Albums tab`

Your `209` magic number means `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary`.
You can use `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumRecentlyAdded` subtype to get "Recents" album, and select "Recents" by default.

Comment: Well, I understand this, but this does not answer the question of where to get all the photos now.

Answer (score 0):

> Where Camera Roll (All Photos) album located now?

Nowhere, *most likely*.

> How can I get it?

```
fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions);
```

Add this to your `fetchOptions` if you need latest images first:

```
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]
```

Comment: This will bring the latest images last, not first.